# number should be separated from specific string format

Tags: php, string, formatting

I'm new in PHP. I've this format of strings `@@##CONTENT-21##@@` including different ids from  content table in my page description section of page table. Just I need to separate the id numbers only & call contents from content table. how can I separate the numbers from the specific format `@@##CONTENT-21##@@` of string?

Comment: What should be the output of @@##CONTENT-21##@@?

Comment: Show us what you have tried, there's plenty of ways to achieve this and plenty of questions having asked the same thing

Comment: use this $str = '@@##CONTENT-21##@@';   $newnumber=filter_var($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

Comment: I need to separate 21 like number which is content id. The format is defined by client to add in page's description section. Different ids can be insert in same description. if I can grab the id then, I'll call the contents for page content.

Answer (score 0):

***First Case***

**If you are sure that all strings start with** `@@##CONTENT-` **and end with** `##@@` you can get the numbers between with the following code, assuming $str is your string and $id is where you will store your ID.

```
$id = substr($str,12,strlen($str)-16);
```

***Second Case***

If you are not sure about the position of the id, but you are sure that **ID is the only number in the string**, you can match it with regular expression, assuming $str is your string and $id is where you will store your ID.

```
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $con_string, $matches);
$id = implode(' ', $matches[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '@@##CONTENT-21##@@';
$newnumber = filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

//if the number is preceeded by a (-) it will also get the (-) so trim the first char
ltrim($newnumber, '-');
```